# Create reports - Matrix with text without aggregation

Tags: matrix, powerbi, report, ssrs-2008

I need to create the following report, the idea is that students will attend to all classes but in any day, the report needs to group who attend to what in a specific day, I'm using power BI report builder, but it's not working[image: report example] [image: table example]

Comment: Is your dataset a SQL Query or a PBI dataset ?

Comment: is a powerbi data set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I got in about 5 minutes was this:

Measure: Student List = CONCATENATEX('Schedule',[Student],UNICHAR(10) & UNICHAR(13))

Matrix with Class on Rows, Day on Columns (you'd need to create separate table of days to force them to sort by the day of the week.), and [Student List] on Values.

Comment: Thanks! It worked on my powerBI, I'll try the same on the report builder

Comment: hello @pieter do you know a workaround for PBI Report Builder? I tried but a matrix on report builder need to pull data from the same data set. I appreciate your time.